# Documentation of PHP development API

Tags: eclipse, api, eclipse-pdt

I'm developing a eclipse plugin. This plugin will collects all function, class, variable,... from PHP source code and generate the function flow (function chart with value of variable, if, else,....).
I can't not find any documentation about PDT api.
Thanks for help.

Comment: The key phrase to search for is 'Abstract Syntax Tree' which finds [Abstract Syntax Tree - PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/ast/PHP_AST.html)

Answer (score 0):

PDT it's not well documented, [see wiki documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT#Developer_Resources). The code is your documentation ;)

Most of api's is inherited from DLTK (model translation, parsers, code assist, type inference), and WTP (syntax highlighting, outline filters, editor validation).

If you are looking for concrete api, you should ask on pdt-dev mailing list.